# {$ obj $} AngularJS syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm not not sure what the syntax `{$ object $}` means, or how to interpret this.

```
angular.module('pagesData', [])
  .value('NUMBER_OF_PAGES', {$ doc.pages | json $});
```

Can someone explain it, or give some reference to a place that specifies how this operator (I guess) works? Is this a syntax specifically for AngularJS or TypeScript?

Comment: Does that actually _work_? It looks like a mish-mash of JS and template syntax.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I saw it in several open sources, [see here for example](https://github.com/mcarmody/CouponBook/blob/bc59ab08573c56908bd9579c1d140150dce5b4ce/angular.js/docs/config/templates/pages-data.template.js)